# WordPress - check if on network admin screen

Tags: php, wordpress, rights

I am looking for a check to see wether or not I'm on the network admin screen in a WPMU.

Sometimes I see this code:

```
if ( ! defined( 'NETWORK' ) ) exit;
```

If you are not on a WP_admin controlpage you get exit. Is there something similar for the pages grouped in Network in wp?

Answer (score 0):

Been looking for some hours now. Found the answer a few minutes after asking

```
            if ( is_network_admin() ) {

                echo "You are viewing a WordPress network 
administration page";

            } else {
                echo "You are <em>not</em> viewing a WordPress network 
administration page";
            }
```