# Action hook for Wordpress network/wp-admin/

Tags: php, wordpress, multisite

I need to perform an action in network admin backend of a wordpress multisite, where url is something like:

website.com/network/wp-admin/

I've tried this type of function:

```
function network_admin_test(){
    if ( is_network_admin() ) {
         echo "You are viewing a WordPress network
administration page";
     } else {
        echo "You are <em>not</em> viewing a WordPress network
administration page";
    }
    
}

do_action('admin_init', 'network_admin_test');
```

But nothing happens...
Any suggestion?
Thank you

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49013075/wordpress-check-if-on-network-admin-screen

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this.

```
function network_admin_test(){
    if ( is_network_admin() ) {
         echo "You are viewing a WordPress network
administration page";
     } else {
        echo "You are <em>not</em> viewing a WordPress network
administration page";
    }
    
}
add_action('admin_init', 'network_admin_test');
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but it still does not work