# is_network_admin() function does not work correctly on multisite

Tags: php, wordpress, multisite

I'm trying to execute this simple function:

```
function network_admin_check() {
    
    if ( is_network_admin() ) {
        echo __( 'You are viewing a WordPress network administration page', 'textdomain' );
    } else {
        echo __( 'You are not viewing a WordPress network administration page', 'textdomain' );
    }
      
}

add_action( 'admin_init', 'network_admin_check');
```

Reference: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_network_admin/

It partially works.
I want to show a message when I'm in website.com/wp-admin/network/ but it only works on the else condition, example when I'm in a subsite backend like website.com/de/wp-admin it shows the message "You are not viewing a WordPress network administration page".

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49013075/wordpress-check-if-on-network-admin-screen